# Absolutely simple SQL Server query doesn't return anything

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2005-express

What I have here is very strange to me...

```
Select BARCODE, DATA 
from HISTORIA 
WHERE BARCODE='25405187' AND DATA = '2013-03-08 00:00:00.000'

Select BARCODE, DATA 
from HISTORIA 
WHERE BARCODE='25405187'
```

Simple right?

Now please look at returned data:

[image]

Ekhmmm... why... Why... WHYYYY? :) As you see proper dates are there, but comparison kills results.

I have SQL Server 2005 Express and the Management Studio Express

Comment: What does `SELECT #2013-03-08 00:00:00.000#` return? I suspect SQL reads the data differently then what it displays, in particular in regards to months/days locations in the strings.

Comment: What data type have `DATA`?

Comment: What happens when you use `'2013-Mar-08 00:00:00.000'` (or the equivalent short month name)?

Comment: Hi. Thx for quick answear. Using this: 2013-Mar-08 00:00:00.000 returns error -> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Comment: SELECT #2013-03-08 00:00:00.000# -> returns error -> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '00'.

Comment: @Oded `DATA` field is datetime type

Comment: @oded if the Sql reads and display data diferently then maybe some kind of date conversion would help. Anyone has experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'2013-03-08 00:00:00.000'` is [not an unambiguous format](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) when casting to `datetime`. It can either mean 3rd of August or 8th of March.

It depends upon your [`DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189491.aspx) settings (which in turn depends upon the language of your login).

```
SET LANGUAGE english

SELECT CAST('2013-03-08 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS english

SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT CAST('2013-03-08 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS british
```

Returns

```
Changed language setting to us_english.
english
-----------------------
2013-03-08 00:00:00.000
```

---

```
Changed language setting to British.
british
-----------------------
2013-08-03 00:00:00.000
```

Use

```
WHERE BARCODE='25405187' AND DATA = '20130308 00:00:00.000'
```

Or more simply

```
WHERE BARCODE='25405187' AND DATA = '20130308'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this standard (ISO) date representation:

```
Select BARCODE, DATA 
from HISTORIA 
WHERE BARCODE='25405187' AND DATA = '2013-03-08T00:00:00.000'
```